# Illegal main-dex-list entry in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to generate a signed bundle/APK for my Android project, but when I do, I come across this compilation error:

`Illegal main-dex-list entry 'src/main/java/{My app bundle}/MainActivity.class'.`

I've googled this issue, and didn't find any solution. How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you added the activity to manifest? it can throw error like this only..

Comment: Yes, it is in the manifest. The application runs on the Android emulator perfectly.

Comment: have you enabled multidexenabled 'true'?

Comment: Yes, I have. Still having that issue.

Comment: Are you using `play-services` in project?

Comment: Yes. I have these imports:  `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0"`

Comment: Did you find the solution? coz I have the same issue